# time costant for a copper conductor

Tags: homework-and-exercises, electric-circuits

My problem is the follow: "find the time costant for a cylindrical copper conductor with infinity lenght knowing the copper conductivity $(5.99*10^7 Ω^-1m^-1)$ and the diameter of the cylinder $(2mm)$".

I know that the time constant $\tau=RC$, the problem is that I cannot find $R$ since the lenght is infinite, neither $C$ for the same reason.

I've found that in particular cases (ex. a conductor inside a capacitor), the time costant can be written as $\tau=\rho*\epsilon_0$: in my case I get $\tau=5,3*10^-18s$, which is very very small and does not use the cylinder diameter.

Any help would be really appreciated.

Thanks.

KB.

Answer (score 0):

The answer is $\epsilon_0/\sigma$.

There is a theorem in electrodynamics that states for low currents, This equation holds for a lump of conductor and two electrodes in it. I can prove it if you want.

$$R=\frac{\epsilon_0}{\sigma C}$$

So $RC$ will be $\epsilon_0/\sigma$.

---

Proof:

Assume this lump of conductor:

[image]

Since $\sigma$ is uniform, we don't have any charge concentration inside. Assuming an arbitrary closed surface around the conductor number 1, we have, for the current flowing from 1 to 2,

$$\frac{\Delta V}{R}=I=\oint_{\mathcal{S}}\mathbf{J}\cdot d \mathbf{a}$$

also, using Gauss's law,

$$C\cdot\Delta V=Q=\epsilon_0\oint_{\mathcal{S}}\mathbf{E}\cdot d \mathbf{a}={\epsilon_0\over \sigma}\oint_{\mathcal{S}}\mathbf{J}\cdot d \mathbf{a}={\epsilon_0\over \sigma}I$$

So,

$$C\cdot \Delta V=\frac{\epsilon_0\Delta V}{R \sigma}\implies R=\frac{\epsilon_0}{\sigma C}$$

QED.